# Do I need to allow the application "stoned" to accept incoming networking connections?

Tags: ruby, macos, maglev

I recently turned my firewall on, and while running multiple rubies, I got the question

> Do you want the application "stoned"
>   to accept incoming network
>   connections?
>
> Clicking Deny may limit the
>   application's behaviour. This setting
>   can be changed in the Firewall pane of
>   Security preferences.

After some googling, I worked out it wasn't a malicous app (and definitely not [this stoned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoned_%28computer_virus%29)!), but maglev (presumably "stoned" being "stone daemon").

Unless I'm serving web content or otherwise acting over the network, do I need to enable "stoned"?

Comment: Maybe doesn't matter too much, but which OS? Also, maybe more something for http://serverfault.com?

Comment: @deceze: If anything, it'd be superuser.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed MagLev, then "stoned" refers to the stone process that manages the repository image (where all your ruby objects are stored).  You can deny stoned (and any others, e.g., topaz, netldi, gem, etc.) and things should work as long as all processes are on the same machine (i.e., you run maglev-ruby on the same machine that is running your stone).  If you are trying to connect remote clients (usually remote VMs) to a stone, then you'll need to allow incoming connections for netldi and gem.

Answer (score 1):

No, definitely don't allow any app to accept connections if you're unsure.